# How to re-order the characters of the string

Tags: python

How to re-order the characters of the string B so that it can be represented as a concatenation of A similar strings.

B is string and A is integer

Function should return 1 if it is possible to re-arrange the characters of the string B so that it can be represented as a concatenation of A similar strings. If it is not, return -1.

- Eg: B = aabb and A = 2, then it is possible to re-arrange the string as "abab" which is a concatenation of 2 similar strings "ab".
- If it is possible, return 1, else return -1.
- Input  `A = 2`, `B = "bbaabb"` output is `1`  We can re-order the given string into `"abbabb"`.
- Input `A = 1` B = `"bc"` output is `1`  String "bc" is already arranged.
- Input `A = 1` B = `"aa"` output is `1`  String "aa" is already arranged.
- A = `2` B = `"aaab"` we cannot reorder this output is -1

Code is below

```
def solve(A, B):
    if B.count(B[0]) == len(B):
        return 1
    comb = combinations(B, A)
    listOfElems = [''.join(i) for i in list(comb)]
    if len(listOfElems) == len(set(listOfElems)):
        return 1
#    for each in range(len(listOfElems)):
#        if listOfElems[each] == listOfElems[each + 1] :
#            return 1
            
    return -1
A = 2
B = "abab"
solve(A, B)
```

My out is `-1` but expected out is `1`, because we can re arrange as `ab` `ab`

Comment: Maybe you can think of a *mathematical rule*, that simply considers the *number of each symbol in the string*, that tells you whether the arrangement is possible? Hint: consider your difficult test case `Input A = 2, B = "bbaabb" output is 1 We can re-order the given string into "abbabb".`. *How did you figure that out*? I bet your thought process was something like: "there are 4 b's and 2 a's in `B`, and `A` is equal to `2` so we divide those: we need to make something with 1 a and 2 b's, and then give A = 2 repetitions of that."

Comment: Another hint: Look at the "aaab" test case. What happens if you try to divide 3 by 2? Can you think of how to write code to test for that issue?

Comment: "If it is possible, return 1, else return -1." This is a *strange* requirement. Python has built-in `True` and `False` values, that you should normally use to represent the answer to yes-or-no questions. Also, code inside `if -1:` *will run*.

Comment: Counting and modulo will be a good first step here.

Comment: Can you give an example of A=3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to log character counts, and then just see if modulo of each count with A is 0, because if not, then you just return -1. Check the code below:

```
def solve(A, B):
    B = B.lower() # optional
    counts = dict()
    for c in B:
        counts[c] = counts.setdefault(c, 0) + 1

    for count in counts.values():
        if not count % A == 0:
            return -1
    return 1

print(solve(2, "abab"))
print(solve(2, "bbaabb"))
print(solve(1, "bc"))
print(solve(1, "aa"))
print(solve(2, "aaab"))
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
-1
```

Using collections module

```
from collections import Counter
def solve(A, B):
    counts = Counter(B)

    for count in counts.values():
        if count % A != 0:
            return -1
    return 1
```

Using NumPy (as suggested by @gilles-ottervanger):

```
import numpy as np
def solve(A, B):
    _, counts = np.unique(list(B), return_counts=True)
    return 2*np.all(counts % A == 0) - 1 # to convert bool to +/- 1
```

Comment: if you are ok with using numpy: `_, counts = np.unique(list(B), return_counts=True)` `return np.all(counts % A == 0)`. But to be honest, this is not really a coding question but rather a general probelm solving question.

Comment: this is working fine why the logic if not count % A == 0:

Comment: @Maws think of it like this, you can only rearrange the characters to make `A` same substrings when the count of each character is a multiple of `A`. So we can just check that the remainder of dividing count with `A` is zero, because if not, we just return `-1` right away as it is not possible to make the desired substrings. If all the character counts are divisible by `A`, then only it is possible.